# New to Racket: why is the if statement affecting the return?

Tags: if-statement, scheme, racket

I just started learning Racket so I am still trying to figure out the intricacies of the language. I am trying to implement my own search function in a list. If the function finds it, it returns the index, otherwise it returns -1.

```
(define (find-index list item)
  (if (equal? (length list) 1)
      (if (equal? (first list) item) 0 1)
      (if (equal? (first list) item)
          0
          (+ 1 (my-search (rest list) item)))))
```

So the find-index function is a recursive function that walks through the list looking for an item that is equivalent to "item." I have written it so that, if there are 4 elements in a list, the function can return any number between 0-4.

```
(define (my-search list item)
  (define length (my-length list))
  (define index (find-index list item))
  (if (= index length) -1 index))
```

My idea is that if the find-index function returns a number equal to the list's length, it means the function did not find the item, therefore my-search function is supposed to return -1.

However, when I put in

```
(my-search (list "apple" "barbecue" "child" "demon" "enter") "fire")
```

the result I get is 3, instead of -1. If I print index before the if statement the index is 3 instead of 5. If

```
(if (= index length) -1 index))
```

is not part of the my-search function then everything is fine.

What I think is going on is that index is the id for the function itself, not the result of the function. However, I don't see why that effects the returning result of my-search. Is anyone willing to shed some light on this question?

Also, any style critique is welcome. I would like to know if I am not following conventions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The weird behavior is caused by the fact that `find-index` is calling `my-search` which is calling `find-index` (a mutual recursion!). At some point, that extra `if` is causing the recursion to end prematurely. Solution: replace the call to `my-search` with `find-index` in the `find-index` procedure.

Now that that was settled, we can write a single procedure for finding an element's index in a list or signaling that it wasn't found, like this:

```
(define (find-index lst item)
  (cond ((empty? lst) #f)
        ((equal? (first lst) item) 0)
        (else
         (let ((result (find-index (rest lst) item)))
           (if result (add1 result) #f)))))
```

Let's see how the above improves your procedure:

- The preferred way to structure a procedure with multiple conditions is to use a `cond`
- You should not use `list` as a parameter name, it clashes with a built-in procedure with the same name
- For the same reason, you should not call `length` a local definition
- It's not a good idea to use `length` for checking if we stepped outside of a list, a well-built recursion will take care of that, without having to iterate over the list all over again
- It's common to use `#f` to indicate that a search procedure didn't find what it was looking for
- In a well-structured recursion over lists, you should check if a list is empty, normally this is the first base case we write - your procedure will fail if an empty list is passed
- We use `let` to declare local variables, in this case it makes sense, to avoid calling the recursion twice
- Use `(add1 x)`, it's more idiomatic than `(+ 1 x)`

But wait, we can do better! The above solution can be rewritten in a *tail-recursive* style; by ensuring that the recursive call is the last thing we do, our procedure will use constant space, and it'll be as efficient as a loop in a conventional programming language. The trick is to pass an extra parameter with the value to return (in this case, the index). I'll use a named `let` for brevity:

```
(define (find-index lst item)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (idx 0))
    (cond ((empty? lst) #f)
          ((equal? (first lst) item) idx)
          (else (loop (rest lst) (add1 idx))))))
```

You can verify that both procedures work as advertised:

```
(find-index (list "apple" "barbecue" "child" "demon" "enter") "fire")
=> #f
(find-index (list "apple" "barbecue" "child" "demon" "enter") "child")
=> 2
```

Comment: This is an incredibly helpful response. I appreciate the bullet points that help me better my code. I also learned that tail-recursion is the right way to go. However, it still does not answer my question of why an if statement would effect the result of index, even before the if statement.

Comment: If I remove the if statement and println index, the index is 5 (given that the item is not found in the list). When the if statement is present, then println index becomes 3. No, the recursion is structured correctly. I get 5 if the item is not found in the list if the last if statement on of my-search function is not there.

Comment: `(define (my-search list item)
  (define length (my-length list))
  (find-index list item))` will return me 5 if it cannot find the item a list of size 4

Comment: @VivienK I found the bug. Yes, definitely your recursion is incorrect: `find-index` is calling `my-search` which is calling `find-index` (a mutual recursion!). At some point, that extra `if` is causing the recursion to end prematurely. Solution: replace the call to `my-search` with `find-index` in the `find-index` procedure.

Comment: Oh my god thank you. I felt like a crazy person. I appreciate you taking the time to debug my code.

Answer (score 2):

That's how I would attack the problem.

```
(define (find-index L item) ; L your list. item the item for which you want the index 
    (define (aux L res) ; Auxiliary function. L your list. item the item for which you want the index 
        (cond ((null? L) -1) ; No thing was found, return -1.
              ((eq? (car L) item) res) ; If the item is equal to the current item then return the position.
              (else (aux (cdr L) (add1 res))))) ; Move on to the next item in the list and increment the position.
(aux L 0)) ; Call of the auxiliary function that will be doing the job
```

Test run...

```
(define L '(a b c d))
```

Element not in the list

```
(find-index L 'e)
```

Output : -1

Element "d"

```
(find-index L 'd)
```

Output : 3

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version of `find-index` that attempts to use the same style as your original example. Instead of `list` I use `xs` (which is short for "list of xes").

Note that it would be better to use the false value `#f` to indicate "not found".

```
(define (find-index xs item)
  (if (empty? xs)
      -1                                                      ; not found
      (if (equal? (first xs) item)
          0                                                   ; found at beginning
          (let ([index-in-rest (find-index (rest xs) item)])  ; index in rest of list
            (if (= index-in-rest -1)
                -1                                            ; not found in rest of list
                (+ 1 index-in-rest))))))                      ; add 1 because we skipped 
                                                                the first element
```